# It Is fine to define all Widget ID with same Variable?

Tags: java, android, xml

I mean is like this

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);    
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){ 

                //Do same logic              

            }
         });
     }
```

it is possible to define like that? or it can causes force close?

and one question again, it is okay to use copying ID from current xml to another xml? i mean the xml was different but the Widget and ID is same, and define the ID in diferrent class. Because it is more simple to copying than make the Same widget with new Id, it is okay?

example :

so in activityone.xml

i had this

[image]

so i was copy the widget to activitytwo.xml so they have a same Widget and ID

[image]

it is okay if i do like that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your second question is, can you reword it? I posted an answer to your first question.

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve* with that code ?

Comment: wait i will update my question with some screenshoot

Comment: @TAsk it is like 5 button do 1 logic i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you should have single listener but five *different* buttons (`Objects`). Currently you are assigning every button one by one to same `button` reference. In that way your `button` will have `R.id.button5` and in further code you won't have reference to your previous buttons `butons1-4`. So, while you add listener to the `button` you are actually adding listener to only button 5 and any other buttons will not have that listener.

First of all you need five different `buttons` and you should create class which implement the listener and add instance of that listener to your `setOnClicklistener` method or in a better way you can just specify `android:onClick="onClick"` in your `xml` and add `onClick` method in your activity.

***FOR EXAMPLE :***

```
//.. on create
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5); 

ListenerClass listener = new ListenerClass();
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
//..and so on

//Create class
public class ListenerClass implements View.OnClickListener {

     //...
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          //You can determine which button is clicked by view.getId()    
          //Add logic here
     } 
 }
```

***OR***

```
public class YourActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   //...on create
   button1.setOnClickListener(this);
   button2.setOnClickListener(this);
   //..and so on
   //...
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       //You can determine which button is clicked by view.getId()    
       //Add logic here
   }
}
```

> it is okay to use copying ID from current xml to another xml?

Yes it is fine but you should avoid using that as it may create confusion in a long run. In a wide project working with a team can create problem in understanding that. Other than that you can have same id because when you call `findViewById` it will refer to the current view and does not get influenced by ids of other views.

Comment: ohh okay i got it, can you take a look with my second question? i have updated the question woth some image

Comment: so it is fine to call findview method in different class and not make the app force close right?

Comment: The first part is false. The second one is opinion-based, and the opinion is at least questionable.

Comment: @TAsk buttons will not be GCed, because they are part of the current view; and they are not created by calls to findViewById.

Comment: @TAsk:  "yes they will" is not a good argument. First paragraph of your answer suggests that code by OP will "create" buttons and that assigning them to a single variable will "get them "garbage collected". Neither is true.

Answer (score 1):

That will only set the listener for button5. Every time you assign button you lose the previous assignment, so when you set the listener the variable button doesn't know that it used to be pointing to button1 to 4.

So no, it will not work.

I put a comment about your second question.